# Edit outlet from different class - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsobject, nsprogressindicator

I need to ***update the value*** of a NSProgressIndicator through a class different from the one where the outlet was defined.

Es:

- In class A.h I define the outlet for the NSProgressIndicator and link it.
- In class A.m I have a method to update the doubleValue of the Indicator.
- **In class B**.m I call, through an istance of class A, the method but **nothing happens**.

Istead if i call the same method **within class A** it **works fine**.

What am I missing ?

```
//REQUESTED CODE:
//Class A (AppDelegate)
A.m
//Other stuff
-(void)update_indicator:(double)value {
//Method that updates the value of the indicator
[progress_indicator setDoubleValue:(double)value];
[progress_indicator setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

//Class B (Drawing class - subclass of NSView)
B.m
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
//Create istance;
A *istance = [[A alloc] init]; //Alloc class A and init it
[A update_indicator:50.0];
//Other code..
}
```

The strange thing is that if I call `-(void)update_indicator:(double)value` within class A, where the outlet is defined, it works fine, if I call it from B it is being called but the progress bar is not showing.

Comment: Probably you have in class B a reference to a different class A object, not to the object that control the interface.

Comment: What would you suggest to do? I set the outlet, declared a property for it and shyntetized. Can't figure out the problem..

Comment: post code for where classB gets a reference to classA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A is the delegate class of the application you can get the good instance using this `[[NSApplication sharedApplication]delegate]`, instead of creating a new instance.

Otherwise, you should make class A a singleton.

Take a lock at this example http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks! This solved my problems!